# Weird Rails 3 scope behavior

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I've implemented the following scope in a rails 3 application:

```
scope :popular, lambda { |l = 5| order('views desc').limit(l) }
```

However, it seems that when you attempt to count its records directly it doesn't apply the scope filters.

For example:

```
Post.popular.size #=> 20
```

Checking the log, it executes the following query:

```
SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM `posts` LIMIT 5
```

Now if I execute

```
Post.popular.all.size #=> 5
```

And the correct query is executed:

```
Post Load (1.5ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` ORDER BY views desc LIMIT 5
```

Anyone else experienced this kind of behavior? If so, any idea if this is the expected behavior or am I facing a bug?

Best regards,
DBA

Comment: Try Post.popular.count, rather than #size. #size should load the collection, then ask the underlying Array. #count will ask the database. #length checks to see if the collection is loaded, and if so, asks the collection, else asks the database. If they return different values, then it might be a bug. Also, the best place to report potential bugs and ask for help is on the Rails mailing list.

Comment: #length returns the expected 5, while #count and #size both return 10 and execute the same query erroneous in the database: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM `posts` LIMIT 5

Comment: If this is a bug, it's been standard rails behavior since before 2.3.